# Mac docker unable to access port 80 with nginx

Tags: macos, docker, nginx

I'm following the tutorial "[Getting started with Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)" but I'm unable to access the nginx home page at localhost. Every time I access localhost, the displayed page is "It works!" which is the default page contained in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en`. I tried to kill all httpd services to remove the binding to the port 80 but it didn't change anything. I also checked that there wasn't any application that was running on port 80 and that neither Skype, MAMP or an Apache server who could be using this port was running.

I think that my Docker installation is correct as I'm able to run the `docker --version`, `docker-machine --version` and `docker-compose --version` without error. I'm running the container with the command described in the tutorial
`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx` but it doesn't work. I tried many ports but it didn't change anything.

Here is the output of a 
[`docker ps`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE8NI.jpg)

So I tried to access the app via 0.0.0.0:80 but it didn't work neither, it always redirect me to the page contained in `Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en`. I tried binding to all kind of ports (8080:80, 8181:81, 8181:80, 8181:8181 ...) and nothing never changed. In those case, I got a page telling me

`"Safari can't connect to server. Safari can't open the page "0.0.0.0:8080" because Safari can't connect to server "0.0.0.0"`.

I also tried replacing `localhost` by `127.0.0.1` but I still have the issue.

If you need further explanations or have any question, ask me. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does it have to be port 80 on your Mac? If not, try `docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name webserver nginx` to map the container's port to port 8080 on your machine and avoid conflicts (unless you have something running port 8080 already :)).

Comment: Please give us your `docker run` command

Comment: @fiskeben As I said in my post, I tried binding to several ports such as 8080:80, 8181:80 and I checked that I didn't have any program using this port.
@gogstad The `docker run` command that I use is quoted in my post : `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx`

Comment: Try reinstalling docker